# I don't know why the variable doesn't add up

Tags: python-3.x

This is my code so far and i don't know why the variable doesn't add up when i loop the code.

```
import random
player1=1
player2=1
print("Welcome To My Board Game")

def dice_roll():
    dice1=random.randint(1,6)
    dice2=random.randint(1,6)
    print("Your first roll is",dice1)
    print("Your second roll is",dice2)
    total_dice=(dice1+dice2)
    print("Your total is",total_dice)
    print("You moved",total_dice,"spaces, to space",player1+total_dice )



while True:
    print("Player 1 Turn")
    choice=input("Do you want to roll the dice press r ")
    if choice.lower()=="r":
        dice_roll()
```

This is the output of my code

```
Welcome To My Board Game
Player 1 Turn
Do you want to roll the dice press r r
Your first roll is 6
Your second roll is 5
Your total is 11
You moved 11 spaces, to space 12
Player 1 Turn
Do you want to roll the dice press r r
Your first roll is 4
Your second roll is 5
Your total is 9
You moved 9 spaces, to space 10
Player 1 Turn
Do you want to roll the dice press r
```

the move space part should add on from the last part

Comment: All your `dice_roll()` variables (`dice1`, `dice2` and `total_dice`) are local and any changes to them disappear after your function returns and its stack gets cleared.

Comment: what should i do to change that

Comment: @samnorman Pass the variables in as parameters so you know the previous value, and return them at the end of the function so the loop can give them back later.

Comment: @Carcigenicate can you show me what you mean i don't understand.

Comment: @samnorman Sorry man, it's been a long day. I going to bed in a bit here. When I get up tomorrow, if I have time, I'll write up an example.

Comment: @samnorman In the meantime, look up "python variable scope". It's extremely important, and it's the source of your confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Use `global` with your var `player1`, and change it every time.

```
def dice_roll():
    dice1=random.randint(1,6)
    dice2=random.randint(1,6)
    print("Your first roll is",dice1)
    print("Your second roll is",dice2)
    total_dice=(dice1+dice2)
    print("Your total is",total_dice)
    global player1
    player1 += total_dice
    print("You moved",total_dice,"spaces, to space",player1)
```

Reference:
[The global statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#global)
[Python Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)

**Edit:**
 Go a step further,you can define a class:

```
import random


class player:
    def __init__(self, init_space=1):
        self.space = init_space

    def dice_roll(self):
        dice1 = random.randint(1,6)
        dice2 = random.randint(1,6)
        print("Your first roll is",dice1)
        print("Your second roll is",dice2)
        total_dice = (dice1 + dice2)
        print("Your total is",total_dice)
        self.space += total_dice
        print("You moved",total_dice,"spaces, to space", self.space)


player1 = player()
player2 = player()
print("Welcome To My Board Game")

while True:
    print("Player 1 Turn")
    choice = input("Do you want to roll the dice press r ")
    if choice.lower() == "r":
        player1.dice_roll()
```

When there are more players, use class will make things easier.

Comment: Although, this should be avoided in most cases. Globals generally make your life harder.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, Yes, you are right. But using globals change few code, and this code seem to be a practice. I edit my answer, Using a class instead of using globals.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, `dice1`, `dice2` and `total_dice` are "destroyed" when the function returns. Those variables are defined within the scope of the function, so they can't be used outside of the function. There are two ways of accessing the variables inside a function:

1. Change global variables, then read the globals somewhere else. @yi_xiao's answer shows an example of this.
2. Pass some data in, and return some data.

In general, you should always prefer returning the values instead of mutating (changing) global variables. Using globals variables makes testing harder, and becomes a problem if you need to access the data from more than one thread at a time.

To fix your code, you should return `total_dice` from `dice_roll`, and pass the old total in:

```
import random
player1=1
player2=1
print("Welcome To My Board Game")

# Pass the old total in as total_dice
def dice_roll(total_dice):
    dice1=random.randint(1, 6)
    dice2=random.randint(1, 6)

    print("Your first roll is", dice1)
    print("Your second roll is", dice2)

    # Increase the running total sum
    total_dice += dice1 + dice2 

    print("Your total is", total_dice)
    print("You moved", total_dice, "spaces, to space", player1 + total_dice)

    # Return the sum
    return total_dice


# Note, in this simple example, sum is actually global.
# In more realistic cases, this would be inside of a function
#  instead of being global 
sum = 0

while True:
    print("Player 1 Turn")
    choice = input("Do you want to roll the dice press r ")
    if choice.lower() == "r":
        # Pass sum to dice_roll
        # Reassing sum to the new sum given to us by dice_roll
        sum = dice_roll(sum)
```

Also note, that currently, your loop won't exit, ever. Even if someone types something other than "r", the loop won't exit, you need to tell it to exit. You can either use `break`, or change from an infinite loop, to something other than `while True`.